# ValueError: Unknown label type: 'unknown' when plotting SVM classifiers in the iris dataset

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I tried to plot SVM classifiers in the Iris dataset [the starting code can be found here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_iris.html). I extended a pandas DataFrame with four extra column that I want to plot in the same manner.

I made the four extra columns with the code :

```
iris = iris.assign(SepalRatio = iris['SepalLengthCm'] / iris['SepalWidthCm']).assign(PetalRatio = iris['PetalLengthCm'] / iris['PetalWidthCm']).assign(SepalMultiplied = iris['SepalLengthCm'] * iris['SepalWidthCm']).assign(PetalMultiplied = iris['PetalLengthCm'] * iris['PetalWidthCm'])
```

I also made an extra specieID colunm :

```
d = {"Iris-setosa" : 0, "Iris-versicolor": 1, "Iris-virginica": 2}
iris['SpecieID'] = iris['Species'].map(d).fillna(-1)
```

Then, I extracted some columns to plot from the DataFrame but after plotting I get the error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-9724675f32fa> in <module>()
     77 xx, yy = make_meshgrid(X0, X1)
     78 
---> 79 for clf, title, ax in zip(models, titles, sub.flatten()):
     80     plot_contours(ax, clf, xx, yy,
     81                   cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, alpha=0.8)

<ipython-input-49-9724675f32fa> in <genexpr>(.0)
     62           svm.SVC(kernel='rbf', gamma=0.7, C=C),
     63           svm.SVC(kernel='poly', degree=3, C=C))
---> 64 models = (clf.fit(X, y) for clf in models)
     65 
     66 # title for the plots

C:\Users\masc\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    150 
    151         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, dtype=np.float64, order='C', accept_sparse='csr')
--> 152         y = self._validate_targets(y)
    153 
    154         sample_weight = np.asarray([]

C:\Users\masc\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py in _validate_targets(self, y)
    518     def _validate_targets(self, y):
    519         y_ = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
--> 520         check_classification_targets(y)
    521         cls, y = np.unique(y_, return_inverse=True)
    522         self.class_weight_ = compute_class_weight(self.class_weight, cls, y_)

C:\Users\masc\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py in check_classification_targets(y)
    170     if y_type not in ['binary', 'multiclass', 'multiclass-multioutput',
    171             'multilabel-indicator', 'multilabel-sequences']:
--> 172         raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
    173 
    174 

ValueError: Unknown label type: 'unknown'
```

My modified code is :

```
from sklearn import svm

iris = pd.read_csv("Iris.csv") # the iris dataset is now a Pandas DataFrame

def make_meshgrid(x, y, h=.02):
    """Create a mesh of points to plot in

    Parameters
    ----------
    x: data to base x-axis meshgrid on
    y: data to base y-axis meshgrid on
    h: stepsize for meshgrid, optional

    Returns
    -------
    xx, yy : ndarray
    """
    x_min, x_max = x.min() - 1, x.max() + 1
    y_min, y_max = y.min() - 1, y.max() + 1
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
                         np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
    return xx, yy


def plot_contours(ax, clf, xx, yy, **params):
    """Plot the decision boundaries for a classifier.

    Parameters
    ----------
    ax: matplotlib axes object
    clf: a classifier
    xx: meshgrid ndarray
    yy: meshgrid ndarray
    params: dictionary of params to pass to contourf, optional
    """
    Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
    out = ax.contourf(xx, yy, Z, **params)
    return out


# import some data to play with
#iris = datasets.load_iris()

iris_numpy_array = iris.as_matrix(columns=None)

print (iris_numpy_array)

# Take the first two features. We could avoid this by using a two-dim dataset
X = iris_numpy_array[:, [1, 2]]

print (X)

y = iris_numpy_array[:, [10]]
y = y.ravel()

print (y)

# we create an instance of SVM and fit out data. We do not scale our
# data since we want to plot the support vectors
C = 1.0  # SVM regularization parameter
models = (svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=C),
          svm.LinearSVC(C=C),
          svm.SVC(kernel='rbf', gamma=0.7, C=C),
          svm.SVC(kernel='poly', degree=3, C=C))
models = (clf.fit(X, y) for clf in models)

# title for the plots
titles = ('SVC with linear kernel',
          'LinearSVC (linear kernel)',
          'SVC with RBF kernel',
          'SVC with polynomial (degree 3) kernel')

# Set-up 2x2 grid for plotting.
fig, sub = plt.subplots(2, 2)
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.4, hspace=0.4)

X0, X1 = X[:, 0], X[:, 1]
xx, yy = make_meshgrid(X0, X1)

for clf, title, ax in zip(models, titles, sub.flatten()):
    plot_contours(ax, clf, xx, yy,
                  cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, alpha=0.8)
    ax.scatter(X0, X1, c=y, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, s=20, edgecolors='k')
    ax.set_xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
    ax.set_ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
    ax.set_xlabel('Sepal length')
    ax.set_ylabel('Sepal width')
    ax.set_xticks(())
    ax.set_yticks(())
    ax.set_title(title)

plt.show()
```

The content of X and Y are the same in the code example as in my code but the only difference is that the're extracted from the pandas DataFrame.

The original code is:

```
print(__doc__)

iris = pd.read_csv("Iris.csv") # the iris dataset is now a Pandas DataFrame

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm, datasets


def make_meshgrid(x, y, h=.02):
    """Create a mesh of points to plot in

    Parameters
    ----------
    x: data to base x-axis meshgrid on
    y: data to base y-axis meshgrid on
    h: stepsize for meshgrid, optional

    Returns
    -------
    xx, yy : ndarray
    """
    x_min, x_max = x.min() - 1, x.max() + 1
    y_min, y_max = y.min() - 1, y.max() + 1
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
                         np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
    return xx, yy


def plot_contours(ax, clf, xx, yy, **params):
    """Plot the decision boundaries for a classifier.

    Parameters
    ----------
    ax: matplotlib axes object
    clf: a classifier
    xx: meshgrid ndarray
    yy: meshgrid ndarray
    params: dictionary of params to pass to contourf, optional
    """
    Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
    out = ax.contourf(xx, yy, Z, **params)
    return out


# import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
# Take the first two features. We could avoid this by using a two-dim dataset
X = iris.data[:, :2]
y = iris.target

# we create an instance of SVM and fit out data. We do not scale our
# data since we want to plot the support vectors
C = 1.0  # SVM regularization parameter
models = (svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=C),
          svm.LinearSVC(C=C),
          svm.SVC(kernel='rbf', gamma=0.7, C=C),
          svm.SVC(kernel='poly', degree=3, C=C))
models = (clf.fit(X, y) for clf in models)

# title for the plots
titles = ('SVC with linear kernel',
          'LinearSVC (linear kernel)',
          'SVC with RBF kernel',
          'SVC with polynomial (degree 3) kernel')

# Set-up 2x2 grid for plotting.
fig, sub = plt.subplots(2, 2)
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.4, hspace=0.4)

X0, X1 = X[:, 0], X[:, 1]
xx, yy = make_meshgrid(X0, X1)

for clf, title, ax in zip(models, titles, sub.flatten()):
    plot_contours(ax, clf, xx, yy,
                  cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, alpha=0.8)
    ax.scatter(X0, X1, c=y, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, s=20, edgecolors='k')
    ax.set_xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
    ax.set_ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
    ax.set_xlabel('Sepal length')
    ax.set_ylabel('Sepal width')
    ax.set_xticks(())
    ax.set_yticks(())
    ax.set_title(title)

plt.show()
```

Comment: You seem to be missing the code you are using to generate the iris dataframe - can you add the full details of that to your modifed code example?

Comment: I just added the line :
iris = pd.read_csv("Iris.csv") # the iris dataset is now a Pandas DataFrame
to create the DataFrame object

Comment: Where did you get the CSV from, or did you create it? It's hard to figure out what the problem is without being able to exactly recreate the dataframe you are using. At a guess I would say it's to do with the column you are using for y - is that definitely the speciesID column? Can you do `iris.info()` after loading your dataframe and post what you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using another template that also makes a SVM plot :

```
from sklearn import svm
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_decision_regions

X = iris[['SepalLengthCm', 'SepalWidthCm']]
y = iris['SpecieID']

clf = svm.SVC(decision_function_shape = 'ovo')
clf.fit(X.values, y.values) 

# Plot Decision Region using mlxtend's awesome plotting function
plot_decision_regions(X=X.values, 
                      y=y.values,
                      clf=clf, 
                      legend=2)

# Update plot object with X/Y axis labels and Figure Title
plt.xlabel(X.columns[0], size=14)
plt.ylabel(X.columns[1], size=14)
plt.title('SVM Decision Region Boundary', size=16)
```

This code gives the plot : [image]

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to do this, and finally (after lot of hours ) here is my code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()

# show data
# print(iris)

# show data columns
# print(iris['feature_names'])

# ========================================

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(iris['data'], columns=iris['feature_names'])
# print(df.head()) 

# tambahkan kolom 'target' => mencerminkan spesies
df['target'] = iris['target']
# print(df.head())

# target mencerminkan nama spesies di target_names
# print(iris['target_names'])

# tambahkan daftar spesies ke dataframe
df['spesies'] = df['target'].apply(lambda x: iris['target_names'][x])
# print(df)

# ========================================

# pisahkan df untuk setiap spesies
df0 = df[df['target'] == 0]     # setosa
df1 = df[df['target'] == 1]     # versicolor
df2 = df[df['target'] == 2]     # virginica

print(df0.head())
print(df1.head())
print(df2.head())

# =======================================

# plot data
fig = plt.figure('Iris Data', figsize=(14,7))

# plot data sepal length vs sepal width
plt.subplot(121)
plt.scatter(df0['sepal length (cm)'], df0['sepal width (cm)'], color='r', marker ='o')
plt.scatter(df1['sepal length (cm)'], df1['sepal width (cm)'], color='y', marker ='o')
plt.scatter(df2['sepal length (cm)'], df2['sepal width (cm)'], color='b', marker ='o')
plt.xlabel('sepal length (cm)')
plt.ylabel('sepal width (cm)')
plt.title('Sepal width vs sepal length')
plt.legend(['0 Setosa', '1 Versicolor', '2 Virginica'])
plt.grid(True)

# plot data petal length vs petal width
plt.subplot(122)
plt.scatter(df0['petal length (cm)'], df0['petal width (cm)'], color='r', marker ='o')
plt.scatter(df1['petal length (cm)'], df1['petal width (cm)'], color='y', marker ='o')
plt.scatter(df2['petal length (cm)'], df2['petal width (cm)'], color='b', marker ='o')
plt.xlabel('petal length (cm)')
plt.ylabel('petal width (cm)')
plt.title('Petal width vs petal length')
plt.legend(['0 Setosa', '1 Versicolor', '2 Virginica'])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

# ===========================================

# split dataset into test & train
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x = df.drop(['target', 'spesies'], axis='columns')  # data utama
y = df['target']                                    # data target

# train dataset dg test = 0.2
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=.2)

print(len(x_train))     # 120 = 80%
print(len(x_test))      #  30 = 20% (hasil dari test_size = .2)

# ============================================

# svm
from sklearn.svm import SVC
# model = SVC()
model = SVC(gamma='auto')   # avoid warning

# train data
model.fit(x_train, y_train)

# akurasi
print(model.score(x_test, y_test))

# ===========================================

# prediksi
print(model.predict([[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2]]))    # output = [0] = spesies setosa
print(model.predict([[7.0, 3.2, 4.7, 1.4]]))    # output = [1] = spesies verticolor
print(model.predict([[5.9, 3.0, 5.1, 1.8]]))    # output = [2] = spesies virginica

# ===========================================

# plot svm

def make_meshgrid(x, y, h=.02):
    x_min, x_max = x.min() - 1, x.max() + 1
    y_min, y_max = y.min() - 1, y.max() + 1
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(
        np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
        np.arange(y_min, y_max, h)
    )
    return xx, yy

def plot_contours(ax, clf, xx, yy, **params):
    Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
    out = ax.contourf(xx, yy, Z, **params)
    return out

iris = load_iris()
X = iris['data'][:, :2]
print(X)
y = iris['target']
print(y)

C = 1.0  # SVM regularization parameter
model = SVC(gamma = 'auto')
model = model.fit(X, y)

fig = plt.figure()

X0, X1 = X[:, 0], X[:, 1]
xx, yy = make_meshgrid(X0, X1)
ax = plt.subplot()

plot_contours(ax, model, xx, yy, cmap='coolwarm', alpha=0.8)
ax.scatter(X0, X1, c=y, cmap='coolwarm', s=50, edgecolors='k')
ax.set_xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
ax.set_ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
ax.set_xlabel('Sepal length (cm)')
ax.set_ylabel('Sepal width (cm)')
ax.set_title('Support Vector Machine')
plt.show()
```

And here is the final result:
[image: SVM lintang wisesa]